# Converting Robot Framework XML to JUnit XML

Tags: python, xml, junit, robotframework

I want a Robot Framework report XML in JUnit format.

Is there a way to produce a JUnit XML from the Robot run itself, or do I need to convert the Robot XML to follow the format of JUnit?

I'm running the Robot script on Python. Apparently the JUnit XML report is only possible if I use Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to produce a JUnit XML from the Robot run itself

Yes, during the execution or even afterwards, by converting RF's native output.xml to xunit format - the latter is through the built-in tool `rebot`:

```
rebot -x xunitOut.xml output.xml
```

The switch [`-x` /`--xunit` (link to the guide)](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#command-line-options-for-post-processing-outputs) can be used both during run, or in post processing.

---

> I'm running the Robot script on Python. Apparently the JUnit XML report is only possible if I use Java.

I don't think that's the case, it's just a format of the execution report xml :)
Keep in mind the xUnit loses some of the metadata that's available in the native format due to their different nature.